# print a screenshot of the desktop and convert in to a matrix of pixels[0,1]

Tags: java, c++

I want to build a program that prints the current screen (every few seconds) and searches for symbol in it.
I already have the function that knows how to find a given symbol in a larger function, however I do not have the followings:

1. How can i capture the current screen (print screen).
2. How do i convert the picture into a matrix of pixels in the range of [0,1], meaning black and white picture.

Currently i only know Java , C , C++, so i need solutions in one of these languages.

I suppose that writing such code may be beyond my knowledge so, links to tutorials will be gladly accepted.

Thank you

Comment: Look at [Java: how to take a screenshot fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912007/java-how-to-take-a-screenshot-fast).

Comment: For C/C++ answers: which OS is your target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a google search and came up with [`this`](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-291473.html), and [`this`](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread209278.html). HTH