# Fast screenshot in Java without Robot

Tags: java, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Is there a way to take a screenshot using java and save it to some sort of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305/java-is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-using-java-and-save-it-to-some-sort-of)

I checked the answers on [How to take screenshots fast in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912007/java-how-to-take-a-screenshot-fast) and was intrigued by finnw's JNA option, but like George I wasn't able to compile the example with the newest jna.jar and the right jar for my platform. I was also not able to add a follow-on comment in George's thread :( Has anybody had any luck writing or compiling a screenshot app in Java using JNA? Is it possible to link JNA in an applet if the applet can detect what platform it's running on?

Thanks.

Comment: alright, i'll ask... why don't you want to use Robot... Just a curiosity or something?

Comment: Because Robot is slow as a dog.

Comment: You've clearly never seen a fit dog run at full speed