# Screen Capture of DirectX programs with Java

Tags: java, opengl, directx

I wrote a Java application that uses the java.awt.Robot to take screen captures of the screen and was wondering if capturing a program using DirectX/OpenGL would be possible?

Each time I try to do this, I get a black screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  But maybe only in limited circiumstances.

I've successfully captured the contents on OpenGL (jogl) windows on linux and windows using the Robot [createScreenCapture](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Some specific information about the implementation that may be different for you:

- The call to createScreenCapture was done from within the OpenGL
  application.
- The application used heavyweight GLCanvas
- It used Java 6

Make sure you pass it the correct coordinates.  You can get the screen coordinates to use from the [GraphicsEnvironment](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is really a solution but seems there's more possible ways to get the screenshot information using a "FrameGrabber" or some related class from JavaCV possibly: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/
Some of the final output shown on the screen could be calculated on a graphics card that has shaders set to act on the image data before it gets put into a display buffer for what's shown so it's possible some effects would be impossible to capture without an analog loopback (go from video out to video in on a capture card).

Related post [How to take screenshots fast in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912007/java-how-to-take-a-screenshot-fast)

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a drawing API, not an all purpose interface to the graphics system. There were times, when taking screenshots with OpenGL was indeed possible through some dirty hacks. However recently I tried to re-implement this on modern OS to see if it still works, and no, it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh... a hard one ;o)

I had a try with some other screenshot utils and got a black screen, too. Looks like DirectX is *passing* the graphics directly to the monitor output. I am wondering if that could be accessed within a java application.