# get the location of a color on the screen

Tags: java

in java, is there any way i can find the location of a color on the screen? so if i know what the color is i get get the current location of it?

i can use the robot class to get a specific color but i need to be able to locate the color on the screen where ever it is.

if this cannot be done with robot or anouther class, i would appresiate it if someone could point me in the right direction by telling me what i need to do. thanks

if so could anyone please help me with what api to use or how to do it?

Comment: So, you can grab a screen shot using Robot, you can find the color in the screen shot, but you can't translate the pixel x/y back to the screen??

Comment: well im trying to find if i can locate the color while its moving so ican click it?

Comment: Ahhh, okay.  I don't think Java has anything that's fast enough to capture the entire screen (a smaller region might be doable) - just to clarify, is this within you program (ie within the applications window) or externally (ie something OS is producing or another application)?

Comment: preferably for games and things. not for personal use, just to learn better java. so any possible way you can think of would be useable by me

Comment: Well, I just did a quick Google and found http://code.google.com/p/java-screen-recorder/ - don't know if it would fast enough, but might worth a look

Comment: ahh, i think i said wrong or you misunderstood, im thinking to make something to do what i mentioned. i have already made a mouse recorder :)

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/234896-faster-screen-capture/
- [How to take screenshots fast in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912007/java-how-to-take-a-screenshot-fast)

The real question is, why am I Goggling this for you :P

Comment: i was really asking if there is a way i can make this happen in my code

Comment: but i do appresiate that you bothered to google anything for someone

Comment: I would have though the second link would have directed you in the right direction.  Basically, as I understand it, you need to get a screen shot (fast) - Robot, but quicker.  From what I've read, these seem to be able to do that :P

Comment: i have never used screen shots just Robots getPixelColor(x, y). could i get every color of every pixel on the screen using this and check if the color is the same as the color i want to click on the screen?

Comment: Sure, I don't know he fast it will be though