# Can't find old Java JNA version

Tags: java, jna

I'm trying to get this to work: [How to take screenshots fast in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912007/java-how-to-take-a-screenshot-fast/4843247#answer-4843247)

Unfortunately it was built using an old version (June 2009) of JNA that I cannot find anywhere. So when I try to run the code with any of the following versions (3.2.3, 3.2.5, 3.2.7 and 3.3.0) I get errors.

I've looked around everywhere but cannot find an old (working) version for Java JNA.
Does anyone know where I could find it?

Comment: Ah ... the joys of using native code ...

Comment: The reason the newer version "doesn't work" is that the platform-specific functions have been moved to `platform.jar`.  If you include that jar file in your classpath in addition to jna.jar, the code should work properly (modulo possibly a few minor import changes).

Comment: Of course I tried to import `platform.jar` - without luck though.

Comment: `platform.jar` will have changed the containing interfaces on some of the functions and/or type definitions.  If you have `platform.jar` in your classpath and load into a decent IDE (eclipse, IDEA, or netbeans) it will offer the appropriate correction for the new import paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna)?  They have versions back to 3.0.3.  I'm not sure which version you are looking for however.

Answer (score 1):

Previous releases are tagged going back five years, and are available from [github](https://github.com/twall/jna/tags).