# How can I capture image of desktop screen in java?

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to take a snapshot of desktop screen in java.
How can i do this.

This is similar to pressing print screen and paste data in ms-paint,
and then save file in .png or .jpg format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912007/java-how-to-take-a-screenshot-fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Copy and paste following code in your Java class and invoke the method
>   captureScreen() with file name as argument. The screen shot will be
>   stored in the file that you specified in argument.
>
> ```
> import java.awt.Dimension;
> import java.awt.Rectangle;
> import java.awt.Robot;
> import java.awt.Toolkit;
> import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
> import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
> import java.io.File;
>
> ...
>
> public void captureScreen(String fileName) throws Exception {
>
>    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
>    Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
>    Robot robot = new Robot();
>    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
>    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));
>
> }
> ...
> ```

Explained in the following link

[how-to-take-screen-shots-in-java-taking-screenshots-jav](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-take-screen-shots-in-java-taking-screenshots-java/)

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = t.getScreenSize();
Image i = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,d.width,d.height));
```

Comment: `r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,d.width,d.height));`

Answer (score 1):

get your screen details from  `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();`

```
GraphicsConfiguration cg // get your screen configuration from above
Rectangle rect = cg.getBounds();
final BufferedImage image;
image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rect);
file = new File(yourFilePath);
String extension = "png" // or any other image extension.
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, extension, file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
robot = new Robot(screen);
Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,d.width,d.height));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
String format = "jpg";
String fileName = "D://FullScreenshot." + format;
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));
```